# Node-sass error (try reinstalling)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sass, gruntjs, node-sass

I'm trying to build a front-end server and when I run grunt I get this error with a suggestion to reinstall node-sass.

```
Aborted due to warnings.
dev@ubuntu:~/ideaProjects/web-app$ grunt app:dashboard/dev-dashboard --force
Loading "sass.js" tasks...ERROR
Error: `/home/dev/ideaProjects/web-app/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.28/binding.node` is missing. 
Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
```

The weird thing is that the file (binding.node) does exist, but it is in a folder named 'linux-x64-v8-3.14' not, 3.28. I tried naming the folder 3.14 that didn't work. I've tried everything I can thing of to get this fixed, npm install node-sass, npm update, even cleaning out the project and running npm install on a fresh build. But to no avail. I repeatedly get this error.

Has anyone seen this or know how to fix this? I am running Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Thanks!

Comment: which command did you use to install grunt-sass? Does it generate any errors / warning?  Here grunt-sass works fine on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Comment: I just ran npm install to install the project dependencies. Is there something else I should run?(I'm new to web development. I'm a java/android developer)

Answer (score 6):

I ran into basically the same error on Debian Linux with gulp-sass(basically same thing as grunt-sass but for gulp...  both are just wrappers for the respective tool around **node-sass** which is a nodejs port of the actual SASS compiler *libsass*).

The **node-sass** project mentions in their [README.md](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#rebuilding-binaries) that only binaries for "popular platforms"(apparently Windows/Mac) are included and you may need to build for other platforms.

I was able to resolve the issue by explicitly re-running the install and build scripts for node-sass directly on the Debian machine. Here are roughly the steps:

- From a command prompt on your linux machine, cd to your project directory
- cd to the node-sass directory within your project source. Probably something like `cd node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass` based on your original post
- `node scripts/install.js`
- `node scripts/build.js`
- Should see a message like `Binary is fine; exiting.`. This will have added the correct node-sass binary for the platform the scripts were run on.
- Try to run your grunt build again and hopefully it should work!

Comment: This almost worked for me, what I had to do is to enter `node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass` and simply run `npm install` from there

Comment: I had a ubuntu running, my problem described slightly different but this post solved it with.
Problem w/ me: ````Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '<MYPROJECTDIR>/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'````
And the vendor folder and contents did not exist.

Answer (score 4):

> I just ran npm install to install the project dependencies. Is there >something else I should run?(I'm new to web development. I'm a java/android >developer)

I do not thinks so. A basic set up, a project folder:

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── node_modules
└── sass
    └── main.scss
```

Gruntfile.js contains:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                'css/main.css': 'sass/main.scss'
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
}
```

then run:

```
npm install grunt-sass
```

Now you should be able to run:

```
grunt
```

the above outputs now:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Done, without errors.
```

Notice that the `npm install grunt-sass` commands should output something like that shown below, possible related to your error:

```
/
> node-sass@3.1.2 install /home/testdrive/sassgrunt/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Binary downloaded and installed at /home/testdrive/sassgrunt/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-14/binding.node

> node-sass@3.1.2 postinstall /home/testdrive/sassgrunt/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

` /home/testdrive/sassgrunt/node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-14/binding.node ` exists. 
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
```

Comment: I ran npm install grunt-sass and the output was the same as you posted, but the error is still there when I run grunt. This is the exact error I get - http://pastebin.com/5arMH4Gr

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks @Bass Jobsen